# Trilateration with N points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let $$C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4, ..., C_n$$ be circumferences of radius $$r_1, r_2, r_3, ..., r_n$$ (respectively) whose centers (beacons) are in points $$(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),...,(x_n,y_n)$$

Is there an algorithm (that could then implemented in a computer) to get the coordinates of the centroid of the area made by the intersection of all those circumferences at the same time?, i.e.: The centroid coords of $$C_1∩C_2∩C_3∩…∩C_n$$

And related to this, how to use this in an applied system like Geodesic or some other longitude-latitude system?

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40660/trilateration-algorithm-for-n-amount-of-points